# Strawberry Plants from Home Depot not producing.

Tags: planting

This is the 3rd year and they have done ok, until this year and no fruit to mention. Planted nicely in ground on retaining wall of rock. Growing very large, should I cut them back or just let continue to let them grow???

Answer (score 4):

My guess:  These are day neutral strawberries.

If they are day neutral strawberries (probably Tristars because that's what I've seen at my Home Depot), then they just need to be replaced. Those do well for a couple of years and then decline rapidly as far as production of berries goes.

If you want a longer-living strawberry plant, consider the June bearing ones.  You'll get runners (also called stolons by fancy plant people in the know, but I call them runners) galore from these, and that's a *very good thing* because that helps keep the plants growing well for years.  The older plants will become less vigorous over time (like the day neutrals do) but the runners will have produced new, more vibrant ones.   I just get rid of the old plants when they stop producing, severing them from the newer ones and that makes room for new runners down the road.  The spent older plants go into the compost bin.

Personally, I like the slightly smaller June bearing ones (e.g., Seneca or Earliglow) but Honeoye's are a large sized berry that is a June bearing variety if you like a larger berry.

It could be any number of reasons why you are having no fruit.  But my money is on those being day neutrals that have come to the end of their lifespan as fruit producers.